# Pattern to enable customization through DI

Tags: angular, angular2-di

I'm looking at the implementation of [in-memory-web-api](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts#L257) and there is the following code:

```
@Injectable()
export class InMemoryBackendService {
  protected config: InMemoryBackendConfigArgs = new InMemoryBackendConfig();
            ^^^^^^
  ...

      constructor(
        @Inject(InMemoryBackendConfig) @Optional() config: InMemoryBackendConfigArgs 
                                                   ^^^^^^
        ) {
        ...
```

As I understand the pattern is the following:

1. Defined class property and instantiate a dependency without using DI
2. Optionally inject dependency

If a user provides modified dependency through DI, it will be injected and the default one instantiated without DI will be overridden. I suspect something similar maybe with `RequestOptions` in `HTTP` module.

Is this a common pattern?

**EDIT**:

It turns out that `in-memory-web-api` is not exactly the pattern I'm asking about. Suppose, I have a class `A` that uses instance of class `B` injectable with the token `B`. So they are both registered with the root injector:

providers: [A, B]

Now, if a user wants to customize `B`, he can register the customized version under the same token, thus effectively overrriding the original `B`:

```
providers: [{provide:B, useClass: extendedB}]`
```

This is how `RequestOptions` can be extended in `http` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value isn't just overridden. The [most important part](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts#L273) here is

```
Object.assign(this.config, config || {})
```

Nothing would happen without it.

This pattern isn't specific to DI, it is a common recipe for default property values, similar to `_.defaults`.

I would say that `InMemoryBackendConfig` [default implementation](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts#L151-L167) is useless abstraction here. Since `this.config` is always merged with `config`, the former could be just a plain object

```
  protected config: InMemoryBackendConfigArgs = { ... };
```

`InMemoryBackendConfig` and `RequestOptions` use complicated variations of this pattern. Yes, in most basic form this is how this can be done:

```
providers: [{provide:B, useClass: extendedB}]`
```

This pattern is widely used by `constant` services in AngularJS for configuration objects, but having `B` as a class instead of plain object allows to extend the original values instead of replacing them.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I missed that they don't provide access modifier for `config` in the constructor. So this is different pattern then. The example with `RequestOptions` of `http` module is more to the point. Let me edit the question.

Comment: by the way, what's your linkedin account?

Comment: Actually, I see RequestOptions as a more complicated version of this and quite unique. Instead of `assign`, It does more complex merging with [merge method](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/http/src/base_request_options.ts#L121). It is a available as [a service](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/http/src/base_request_options.ts#L219) but used through [another helper function](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts#L21-L40)..

Comment: I've updated the answer. Yes, the pattern you've suggested is supposed to work like that. I would personally stick to an injectable class for config objects. Angular built-ins aren't the best examples because they are instantiated directly with `new` as well, this doesn't make the things more simple.