# Angular 5 Injector - How to inject string

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular5

I am trying to inject strings into my angular component.
The code below works fine but it gives a deprecation warning:
*get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type or InjectionToken*

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-label',
  templateUrl: './label.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./label.component.scss']
})
export class LabelComponent {
  public name: string;
  public caption: string;
  constructor(
    private injector: Injector
  ) {
    this.name = this.injector.get('name');
    this.caption = this.injector.get('caption');
  }
}
```

So i tried to work with this very short and incomplete documentation [Angular 5 Injector](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector)
 to come up with something like below, however I don't want to `useValue` or `useClass`, what I need is the actual value injected.

```js
    class BS { }
    // [..]
    const name = new InjectionToken<string>('name');
    const caption = new InjectionToken<string>('caption');
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      { provide: name, useClass: BS},
      { provide: caption, useClass: BS}
    ]);
    this.name = this.injector.get(name);
    this.caption = this.injector.get(caption);
    console.log(this.name); // will be an instance of BS
```

I am really stuck here and the documentation is not helping at all.

I need this for Dynamic component Loading and Injection. Full Plunker can be found in: [Plunker Dynamic Component Loading and Injection](https://embed.plnkr.co/p7VHB4/)

Comment: Why are you saying that you don't want to `useValue` or `useClass`?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel because I am not mocking the values. I need to capture the actual value injected rather that falling back on a useValue if my injection is fails.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. The `useValue` and `useClass` provider values are just telling Angular if you are providing a static value or a class to instantiate. These look like they might be UI strings. Have you looked into using a translation library for injection of these strings? An example would be ngx-translate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type or InjectionToken

warning refers to the fact that `injector.get` is generic method and expects type argument. This is exactly what [`Injector` documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) states:

> get(token: Type | InjectionToken, notFoundValue?: T): T

Considering that `name` string token is supposed to resolve to a string, it should be:

```
this.injector.get<string>(<any>'name');
```

String tokens are deprecated as well, and a token is expected to be either a function or `InjectionToken` instance.

> however I don't want to useValue or useClass, what I need is the actual value injected.

All dependencies should be registered as module or component providers in order to be injected.

Comment: unfortunately this is not how it works. `this.injector.get<string>('name');` won't work because `Argument of type '"name"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InjectionToken<string> | Type<string>'.`

Comment: I updated the answer with explanation. String tokens are deprecated, and you have to cheat it with `<any>`. In your case https://embed.plnkr.co/p7VHB4/  I see no reason why string tokens should be used. You can use InjectionToken there.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more `I see no reason why string tokens should be used. You can use InjectionToken there`

Comment: Because string tokens provide global-like behaviour. You can use token in another module without importing it. They have some drawbacks as globals - loose coupling, namespace pollution and collisions. String tokens were considered antipatterns for these reasons and so were deprecated.

Comment: ok that is clear, but what do you suggest to use? `this.injector.get<string>(<any>'name');` is this the right way or an even better option to create a class and inject it instead of single properties?

Comment: It depends on the case. In your case there doesn't seem to be reasons why there should be many providers. You could create a single `componentConfig` InjectionToken provider with `name` and `payload` props. As for ReflectiveInjector, it is usually not necessary, and I guess here too - usually you can pass data to dynamically created component through `inputs`.

Answer (score 15):

First you need to create an [`InjectionToken`](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#non-class-dependencies) (here in `values.ts`):

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const PAGE_TITLE = new InjectionToken<string>('page.title');
```

Then you need to import it into your module and provide a value when that token is requested:

```
providers: [ HeroService, MessageService,
    { provide: PAGE_TITLE, useValue: "My Wonderful Title" }
],
```

Then you need to import that token where you want to inject the value and use `@Inject()`:

```
constructor(@Inject(PAGE_TITLE) title) {
  this.title = title;
}
```

[Sample on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4vnxhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Looking at [`ReflectiveInjector`](https://angular.io/api/core/ReflectiveInjector) it says it is slow and to use [`Injector.create`](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) instead btw...

Comment: That's not what I am looking for actually, I could achieve the same with the code above and `useValue`

      `{ provide: name, useValue: 'bs1'},
      { provide: caption, useValue: 'bs2'}`

The injected values are dynamic and coming from another service.

Comment: I'm don't understand, if the values are being provided by a service, shouldn't the service be injected?  Are you trying to create a service that ties into the injection at run-time and dynamically alters the values that will be injected when new instances are created?

Comment: @Royalsmed Then the question is XY problem. Generally you don't need to use ReflectiveInjector at all for regular tasks. If you need it, you can be sure that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @estus I don't think I am doing something wrong but I might be wrong :p here is a full Plunker with what I am trying to achieve [link](https://embed.plnkr.co/p7VHB4/)